# ImportError when trying to install "worldengine"

Tags: python, installation, pip, importerror

Tried to install this tool here https://github.com/Mindwerks/worldengine.

pip install git+https://github.com/Mindwerks/worldengine.git gives me
[this error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwxwI.jpg)

I get the same error when installing it manually with the source setup.py.

I'm a total beginner to Python and coding in general so I really don't know how to solve this myself. The tool is quite old and discontinued, so I'm using Python 2.7 to install since Python 3 just brings up a whole load of other error messages.

Comment: No, you're using Python 3.10.  The error says so.  Try `py -2 pip install git+etc` to force it to use Python 2.

Comment: The console then tells me: C:\Python27\python.exe: can't open file 'pip': [Errno 2] No such file or directory.  There is a pip file in Scripts. How do I get pip for 2.7?